# How can I use generic Type from getType object

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I have `MyClass<T>`

```
var Myobj = authorObject.getType();
```

How can I instantiate `MyClass` object from `Myobj` var

I tested this code and it didn't work

```
var x = new MyClass<Myobj>();
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code and where you getting this issue?

Comment: see about [Type.MakeGenericType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you do not know the type you want to provide as a type argument for MyClass before. You can create a type dynamically through reflection, e.g.:

```
var testVar = 123;
var genType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(testVar.GetType());
var genInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(genType);
Console.WriteLine(genInstance.GetType().FullName);
```

- [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates a type Definition of a generic type with the provided type arguments.
- [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates a new instance for a given type and constructor arguments (that I omitted for simplicity). If MyClass needs constructor arguments, you have to provide them here.

If you need to access specific members of `MyClass<T>`, I suggest to create an non-generic interface (or base class) that contains the required members and that MyClass implements (derives from respectively). You can then cast the return of Activator.CreateInstance to that interface and use the members the interface defines. 
If you want to access members of `MyClass<T>`that rely on the generic type argument, you have to access them dynamically through reflection as the generic type definition was created dynamically. You can use the [InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.InvokeMember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for that. In the following sample, I assume that `MyClass<T>` contains a property Value of type T that I get the value of:

```
object value = genType.InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.Public | 
                                                 BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                 BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                                             null, genInstance, null);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

If you know the type of value at design time, you can also cast the return value of InvokeMember.

For a full sample, please see this [link](http://ideone.com/LrnXNo).

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object` can you provide sample to get unboxing value?

Comment: @Grundy That makes no sense. You cannot use a type that is only known at run-time at compile-time.

Comment: @Grundy: I've extended the answer and also provided a link to a full sample that contains the various methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Type.MakeGenericType and Activator:

```
Type genType = typeof(MyClass<>);
Type type = genType.MakeGenericType(typeof(MyObj);

var x = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```